# grep regex to check if lines contains subdomain

Tags: regex, string, ubuntu, search, grep

I have a file that contains domain names. I want to search for and remove the lines that are for sub-domains. Subdomains contains more than one dot (.). Examples:
Sub-domain: `ab.cd.fg` or `ab.cd.fg.hi`. 
Full domains contains one dot: `ab.cd`

I am not sure if my regex is correct and going to capture any subdomains despite the number of dots:

```
grep '.\..(\..)+' myfile.csv
```

The above is my attempt to search for lines which contains sub-domains. How can remove them and save the new filtered results in a new file?

Sample input:

```
ab.cd.fg
ab.cd
ab.cd.fg.hi.jk
```

Output should be a file cleaned from lines with subdomains which are the lines with one dot.

```
ab.cd
```

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: from what I understand, you want `grep -v '\..*\.'` or `awk -F. 'NF==2'` ... there is a duplicate somewhere..

Comment: Your requirements are incomplete. `yahoo.co.uk` and `poughkeepsie.k12.ny.us` are top-level domains in their respective hierarchies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the job:

```
grep -P '^[^.]+\.[^.]+$' input_file
```

Where

- `-P`      : perl regex
- `^`       : beginning of line
- `[^.]+`   : 1 or more any character that is not a dot
- `\.`      : a dot
- `[^.]+`   : 1 or more any character that is not a dot
- `$`       : end of line

Comment: Nothing in this regex requires the `-P` option, which is nonstandard and thus not entirely portable. Just drop the option.

Comment: @tripleee: It doesn't work for me without `-P`.  (Linux Mint in Virtualbox)

Comment: You need `-E` instead, or backslash the pluses. The `-E` option is defined in POSIX and widely portable. But yeah, sorry, I overlooked the fact that you used `+` (which was introduced in `egrep`) instead of `*` (which was in Thompson's original `grep`).

Comment: @tripleee : OK.